# XoffLimit, XonLimit - what does it mean?

Tags: serial-port

I am adjusting some parameters of RS-232 line. I ran accross these two parameters - XoffLimit, XonLimit. Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control) suggets that this has to do with software flow control. Their values are XoffLimit = 1024, XonLimit = 1024. What is significance of this? What difference if I set XoffLimit = 1024, XonLimit = 2048?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xon / Xoff is software flow control done by inserting escape characters in the data stream.  I would doubt you need it and you probably shouldn't use it.  Both sides would have to be configured to understand the escape chars.

But basically, when your input serial buffer reaches XonLimit, then the serial port would send an XOFF byte to make the other side stop sending.  Then when your input buffer dropped down to XoffLimit, the XON byte would be sent to allow sender to resume.